# Does Neo4j Bloom can sort the entities in visualization?

Tags: sorting, neo4j, entity, bloom

My database is set up, and when I query it and visualize the result in Bloom, I should manually sort one of the entities in a line to make it more meaningful for the audience. I am wondering if it is possible to sort the entities in Bloom, i.e. from left to right in a horizontal line?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In Bloom at the bottom right of the perspective view you can select the layout algorithm to use to display nodes and relationships: in your case you could use a hierarchical layout or if you have measurable and meaningful properties you could use the coordinate layout and distribute your nodes based on those.

[image]